# Android DayNight Theme with configChanges

Tags: android, rotation, orientation

I'm creating an app where I use the theme DayNight of the Android support libraries.

This is the code in themes.xml

```
<style name="ActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I use configChanges in the manifest to manage rotations.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

In the onCreate on my AppcompatActivity I have added:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

The problem is that when I use setDefaultNightMode, android:configChanges stops working, and recreate de activity in every rotation.

Any kind of help will be welcome

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need to add '**uiMode**' parameter to your **manifest**:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|uiMode|keyboardHidden"
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a bug and will be fixed in AppCompat v.1.1.0 according to this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74022852).

Until its fixed I would add the `uiMode` flag to `android:configChanges` like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53763913/6265645)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with AppCompat v1.1.0, setDefaultNightMode() automatically recreates any started activities.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#changing_themes_in-app

Answer (score 1):

This [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74022852) has been fixed with AppCompat v1.1.0-alpha05.

See here: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/darktheme#changing_themes_in-app

> **Note**: Starting with `AppCompat` v1.1.0-alpha05, **setDefaultNightMode()** does not automatically recreate any started activities.

Update your appcompat dependency to the [latest](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat) version, currently 1.1.0-rc01.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
```

Don't forget to remove the `uiMode` flag from `android:configChanges` in your manifest if you added it.

Comment: We are using latest dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0', but ui theme is still not updating in onConfig change