# How to avoid restarting activity on orientation change in DayNight mode?

Tags: android, orientation, activity-lifecycle

I am trying `daynight mode` in my application. My problem is, activity is recreating on orientation changes. It works fine with `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)` . But when I set `nightmode` to **`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)`** and changing orientation it leads to **activity restart**. I tried `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. But no help. Now my question is that how can I avoid to restart activity on orientation changes with `AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES`. Sorry for my poor English. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55846432/6265645)

Summary

- It is a bug and will be fixed in AppCompat v1.1.0 (and is already fixed since v1.1.0-alpha03).
- Until its fixed I would add the `uiMode`-flag to `android:configChanges`.