# Activity is recreated when screen rotation changes if-and-only-if Night Mode is ON

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-resources, android-night-mode

I have this `Activity` (subclass of `AppCompatActivity`):

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.settings.SettingsActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|smallestScreenSize|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:parentActivityName=".ui.main.MainActivity" />
```

Now, when I rotate the phone while in normal (i. e. "Day") mode I get a call to `onConfigurationChanged` but the `Activity` is not re-created.

However, when the app is set to Night Mode (by calling `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)` in my `Application` before the `Activity` is created) and I *then* rotate the phone, I first get a call to `onConfigurationChanged` but then the `Activity` is *also* re-created, even though the `uiMode` has not changed at all! This goes away when I add `uiMode` to the `configChanges` that should be ignored in my `AndroidManifest.xml`, but it seems weird that I need to do this.

From looking through the source it seems that:

- `onConfigurationChanged` calls `getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);` which goes to `AppCompatDelegateImpl.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)`
- there, `applyDayNight()` gets called
- there, `getNightMode` returns `AppCompatDelegateImpl.MODE_NIGHT_YES`, which makes sense since this is what I set it to. `mapNightMode` just returns that value unchanged. Then `updateForNightMode(AppCompatDelegateImpl.MODE_NIGHT_YES)` gets called
- there, `newNightMode` is calculated correctly to be `Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES` *but* `currentNightMode` (which is read in from `mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode`) always appears to be `Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO` after each rotation, even if the `Activity` was rendered in Night Mode *before* the rotation.

So, what's going on here and what could I do to get more consistent behavior? (Re-create (or not) the `Activity` after a screen rotation, regardless of whether the app is in Night Mode or not.)

Comment: Seems like you need to add `uiMode` to config change list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313812/android-daynight-theme-with-configchanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug and will be fixed in AppCompat v1.1.0 according to this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74022852).

Starting with AppCompat v1.1.0-alpha03 you no longer need the `uiMode`-flag in the `configChanges` as a workaround